# How to load page in application.hbs?

Tags: ember.js

I want to load a connexion page then a home page with a navbar etc...

My problem is about `{{partial}}` and `{{outlet}}`.

I don't really understand because when I `{{#link-to}}` my next home page, connexion is still here... I don't know what instruction write in `application.hbs` in order to load `Connexion.hbs` then `index.hbs` with navbar... Can someone help and explain me ?

I just want to load `connexion.hbs` when I load my website, then I click on "sign in" I want to load another page with a navbar (I already have this code, thanks bootstrap) and home page. I just need some link between my pages.

EDIT : I changed my `connexion.hbs` route's path into `/` everything is ok now ! Thanks !

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

First: *never* use `{{partial}}`!

Next everything you put in the `application` route is visible *the whole time*! So thats usually only your navigation.

Different pages you want should be different routes. The first route visible is the `index` route.